# Binary inflation error while inflating floating action button

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

Im trying to embed Floating Action Button .Following is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/proformo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="PI 12343"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shippingStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Cargo Shipped"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shippingDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="on07 oct 2015"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="PI 12345"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="on Dec 2016"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Shipment Ref.# :"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

                    android:textColor="#000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="4312412412"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etdLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ETD:"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etdValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="24 oct 2015"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etaLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ETA:"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etaValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="09 dec 2014"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/networkImage"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/noimage" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/quantity_label"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Quantity: "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/quantity_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="40mts"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/amount_label"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Amount: "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/amount_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="200 USD"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rate_label"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Rate"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rate_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="40 USD"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shipped"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Shipped By "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shippedcompany"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that Im getting the following error message,

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #300: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>                                                                    at com.vaighai.adapters.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:74)
>                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
>                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1259)
>                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1171)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
>                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
>                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
>                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
>                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
>                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2189)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1535)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
>                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
>                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
>                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
>                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(

How can i sort this out?

Comment: seriously? FloatingActionButton as a part of ListView item ?

Comment: This looks like it's used to inflate a ListView Item, like @Selvin said. Please post some more related code.

Comment: yes.... Im trying to embed it upon each items of listview

Comment: *Don’t have more than one floating action button per screen.* *Don’t associate floating action buttons with every element on a screen.*  from [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html)

Comment: ok thank you...I will remove it then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `"?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`piece. Inflate cannot inflate elements which utilize such elements.